# Error when make a controller on AdonisJS5

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

When I try to run the command

```bash
node ace make:controller User
```

displays the following error

Cannot find module './commands/Make\Controller'
Require stack:

- /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/assembler/build/noop.js

  1  resolveFileName
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:29

  2  resolveFrom
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:43

  3  module.exports
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:46

  4  resolveFrom
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/node_modules/@poppinss/utils/build/src/Helpers/resolveFrom.js:25

  5  ManifestLoader.loadCommand
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Manifest/Loader.js:95

  6  Kernel.find
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:384

  7  Kernel.execMain
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:177

  8  Kernel.handle
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/ace/build/src/Kernel/index.js:553

  9  App.handle
  /Users/abiliocoelho/Desktop/socket/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/src/Ignitor/Ace/App/index.js:226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the framework, it should be fixed by now. Ensure to update your dependencies.

https://github.com/adonisjs/assembler/releases/tag/v5.9.2

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the project directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).